JSdoc preserving comment formatting
How can I preserve the formatting of this comment in JSDoc without wrapping it in a code block?
I have a comment in the code that explains the format of a string that represents the an event. I would like to preserve the formatting without the "CODE" bar.
The comment:
Event structure "mm/dd/T:text"
mm              month 1-12
dd or position  day of month ( 1-31 or day position )
T               Event type "H" = Holiday, "I" = Information, "P" = Personal
text            Displayed text

I tried @example,<pre> and <code> but all of them added the "CODE" bar.
Here's the JavaScript code:
    /**
     *  Add an event.
     *  
     *  Event structure "mm/dd/T:text"
     *   mm              month 1-12
     *   dd or position  day of month ( 1-31 or day position )
     *   T               Event type "H" = Holiday, "I" = Information, "P" = Personal
     *   text            Displayed text
     * 
     *  The day position:
     *   First 3 characters are the day of the week.
     *   Followed by the position first, second, third, fourth or last.
     *   The day position ignores case.
     *
     *  @param {string} ev - The event
     */
    static addEvent(ev) {
        this.events.push(ev);
        this.display();
    } // End of addEvent


BTW I'm using the clean-jsdoc-theme.
